# Is there a "private" web service in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

We host MS CRM and Sharepoint in the Cloud and want to implement a web service that communicates between these two apps. We plan to have a button in CRM that calls the service (via Javascript). The service then retrieves some information from Sharepoint and this information is then finally displayed in CRM.
What is the best option for this in Azure? I am thinking of a Web Role with the service deployed but I don't want to have the web service publically visible. Can I have a "private" service that is only avaiable from inside of my Cloud?

Comment: Is a Hybrid Connection (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/) what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think so. Hybrid Connection seems to be a whay to connect azure with on premise data. But in my case all data is hosted in the cloud.
What I am looking for is a way to deploy a web service in Azure that is not public and that has a static url  to consume it from Javascript.